# In Apache Spark. How to set worker/executor's environment variables?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, apache-spark, distributed-computing

My spark program on EMR is constantly getting this error:

```
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSessionImpl.getPeerCertificates(SSLSessionImpl.java:421)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:128)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:397)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:148)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:149)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:121)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:573)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:425)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:820)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:754)
    at org.jets3t.service.impl.rest.httpclient.RestStorageService.performRequest(RestStorageService.java:334)
    at org.jets3t.service.impl.rest.httpclient.RestStorageService.performRequest(RestStorageService.java:281)
    at org.jets3t.service.impl.rest.httpclient.RestStorageService.performRestHead(RestStorageService.java:942)
    at org.jets3t.service.impl.rest.httpclient.RestStorageService.getObjectImpl(RestStorageService.java:2148)
    at org.jets3t.service.impl.rest.httpclient.RestStorageService.getObjectDetailsImpl(RestStorageService.java:2075)
    at org.jets3t.service.StorageService.getObjectDetails(StorageService.java:1093)
    at org.jets3t.service.StorageService.getObjectDetails(StorageService.java:548)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.retrieveMetadata(Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.java:172)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor18.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:103)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.$Proxy8.retrieveMetadata(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem.getFileStatus(NativeS3FileSystem.java:414)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.exists(FileSystem.java:1398)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem.create(NativeS3FileSystem.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:906)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:887)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:784)
```

I did some research and found out that this authentication can be disabled in low-security situation, by setting environment variable:

```
com.amazonaws.sdk.disableCertChecking=true
```

but I can only set it with spark-submit.sh --conf, which only affects driver, while most of the errors are on workers.

Is there a way to propagate them to workers?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just stumbled upon something in the [Spark documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.0/configuration.html#runtime-environment):

`spark.executorEnv.[EnvironmentVariableName]`

> Add the environment variable specified by EnvironmentVariableName to
>   the Executor process. The user can specify multiple of these to set
>   multiple environment variables.

So in your case, I'd set the Spark configuration option `spark.executorEnv.com.amazonaws.sdk.disableCertChecking` to `true` and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I just found that in the official documentation, don't know why it was ignored before

Comment: Easily overlooked option. This saved me some headache, thanks.

Comment: I need the same thing but on the `worker` :  going to see if that were available ..

Answer (score 7):

Adding more to the existing answer.

```py
import pyspark


def get_spark_context(app_name):
    # configure
    conf = pyspark.SparkConf()
    conf.set('spark.app.name', app_name)

    # init & return
    sc = pyspark.SparkContext.getOrCreate(conf=conf)

    # Configure your application specific setting

    # Set environment value for the executors
    conf.set(f'spark.executorEnv.SOME_ENVIRONMENT_VALUE', 'I_AM_PRESENT')

    return pyspark.SQLContext(sparkContext=sc)
```

`SOME_ENVIRONMENT_VALUE` environment variable will be available in the executors/workers.

In your spark application, you can access them like this:

```py
import os
some_environment_value = os.environ.get('SOME_ENVIRONMENT_VALUE')
```

Answer (score 1):

Building upon other answers, here is a full example that works (PySpark 2.4.1). In this example I am forcing all the workers to spawn only one thread per core in Intel MKL Kernel library:

```
import pyspark

conf = pyspark.conf.SparkConf().setAll([
                                   ('spark.executorEnv.OMP_NUM_THREADS', '1'),
                                   ('spark.workerEnv.OMP_NUM_THREADS', '1'),
                                   ('spark.executorEnv.OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS', '1'),
                                   ('spark.workerEnv.OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS', '1'),
                                   ('spark.executorEnv.MKL_NUM_THREADS', '1'),
                                   ('spark.workerEnv.MKL_NUM_THREADS', '1'),
                                   ])

spark = pyspark.sql.SparkSession.builder.config(conf=conf).getOrCreate()

# print current PySpark configuration to be sure
print("Current PySpark settings: ", spark.sparkContext._conf.getAll())
```

Answer (score 1):

For spark 2.4 , @Amit Kushwaha 's method doesn't work.

I have tested:

### 1. cluster mode

```
spark-submit --conf spark.executorEnv.DEBUG=1 --conf spark.appMasterEnv.DEBUG=1 --conf spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.DEBUG=1 --conf spark.yarn.executorEnv.DEBUG=1 main.py
```

### 2. client mode

```
spark-submit --deploy-mode=client --conf spark.executorEnv.DEBUG=1 --conf spark.appMasterEnv.DEBUG=1 --conf spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.DEBUG=1 --conf spark.yarn.executorEnv.DEBUG=1 main.py
```

None of above can set enviroment variable into executor system(aka. can not read by `os.environ.get('DEBUG')`)  .

---

### The only way is get from spark.conf:

submit:

```
spark-submit --conf DEBUG=1 main.py
```

get variable:

```
DEBUG = spark.conf.get('DEBUG')
```